# Deploying applications on OpenShift

Tags: deployment, openshift

I am building an application for OS(OpenShift) and was wondering is it possible to deploy code which is not in the git repo, like uploading plugins to a wordpress site?

**NOTE**

The application is not a WP site, nor related in any way to a similar CMS. SO i need a way to deploy additional code after deployment without pushing it to the repo.

Comment: You can use sftp, scp, or update via ssh if you'd like.  Here's a blog on how to use Netbeans which uses SFTP:  https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-sftp-and-openshift

Answer (score 0):

As Nam said, you can just use scp, sftp etc.  However, keep in mind that this could cause problems down the road as when you scale up we rsync the repo over.

Comment: gshipley, what if I have application deployed to several gears. Do I have to manually scp it to each gear?