# Deploy a war file to OpenShift WildFly

Tags: openshift, java-ee-7, wildfly

I developped a Java EE 7 application, that runs fine locally with WildFly 8.

I'd like to deploy it to OpenShift. I created an account, added a WildFly 8 cartridge, declared the application, installed Ruby and RHC locally.

Now, I'm stuck at the next step, the deployment of my war file.

All articles, OpenShift documentation, other StackOverflow entries, etc... mention using Git! I'm really surprised here, since I have no interest in using or learning Git. I already have up and running version control and even automated build solutions (SVN and Maven for the curious). In addition I do not want OpenShift to have my application sources. I just want to be able to upload the war file to OpenShift.

How do I simply upload my war file to OpenShift WildFly?

Thank you for your time.

**Update 1**

I found a way to choose manual deployments, using "*rhc configure-app myapp --no-auto-deploy --deployment-type binary*". This worked fine.

Then I think I'm supposed to use "*rhc deploy some\path\myapp.war --app myapp*". But this fails (some stuff are hidden by me using "X"s):

```
Deployment of file 'D:/foo/bar/myapp.war' in progress for application myapp ...
Starting deploy for binary artifact
Stopping gear
Stopping wildfly cart
Creating new deployment directory
Preparing deployment
Preparing build for deployment
gzip: stdin has more than one entry--rest ignored
/bin/tar: Child died with signal 13
/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
An error occurred executing 'gear binary-deploy' (exit code: 2)
Error message: Unable to extract deployment archive using command: /bin/tar -xz

For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
Error deploying local file. You can try to deploy manually with:
ssh -t XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com 'oo-binary-deploy'
SSH command finished with exit status = 255
```

According to the documentation, I'm not sure if the "rhc deploy" command supports standard war files.

Maybe, instead, I'm supposed to manually copy the file as described in https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear

Comment: To be fair, once you deploy the war they have your code. Period. As for the deployment, a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18695599/785663) mentions this link: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-sftp-and-openshift so you can obviously deploy with a simple copy once you've setup ssh keys.

Comment: The link describes how to upload the sources using SFTP, not the binary. No cookie for you. :)

Comment: The best I found so far is "rhc help deployment" that mentions the possibility to deploy from a binary file. I still don't know how though.

Comment: Next cookie attempt: have you seen https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-Configuring_Application_Deployment.html ? Seems like `rhc configure-app App_Name --deployment-type binary; rhc deploy ./app.war -a App_Name` should do it.

Comment: Yes I discovered that yesterday. I updated the question.

Comment: Well, binary deployment is explicitly mentioned as an option for "Java developers". So this *should* work. But I've enough of the guessing game: [using the source](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/node/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container_ext/deployments.rb) now. And from the face of it, naming your war "myapp.zip" should at least get it past this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go is via scp as described here - https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear

Comment: I think the main point is that there's no way to do the job *without touching git*. The OP needs to use it to first remove the default "template" files OpenShift generated before proceeding to normally push files via SCP.

Comment: Right, you need to use git at some stage. It is just a central part of how Openshift works. On the other and, you only need to do it once in this case to remove the src tree and the POM. After that you can start/stop the app using the rhc tool and deploy via scp. If it comes down to it and you really don't want to clone locally (not sure why you wouldn't want to though), you could ssh onto your gear and do the required git changes there.

Comment: What about multiple gears?
As far as I understand, if you deploy the application manually (via scp) - you will have to do it manually on all the gears you have. Am I right?

Comment: Was looking for exactly that description - link is dead however. That is why we encourage putting the gist of the solution in the answer.

Comment: This link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

You can do rhc port-forward and then access the web console like the directions at the bottom of the readme on this github repo: https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-wildfly-cartridge